# How can I create an instance of projected type in Scala?

Tags: scala

I use Type Projection. You can find in the example below a type alias.

```
object Example extends App {
  type AliasForY = X#Y

  class X {
    class Y {
      def fun = 100500
    }
  }

  def f(y: AliasForY) = y.fun

  println {
    f(new AliasForY())
  }

}
```

I want to instantiate my inner class via alias, but I get an error `Example.X is not a legal prefix for a constructor`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Inner classes can't be instantiated outside of their containing class. If you want to create new instances of `Y` outside of `X`, `X` needs to be an `object`.

Comment: That's correct, unless you put `Y` in the companion object instead.

Answer (score 1):

To create an instance of inner class, you should have an instance of its containing class. So this would work:

```
val x = new X
f(new x.Y())
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to create an instance on inner class. What I don't know is why we need projected types in Scala like this `type AliasForY = X#Y` if we just cannot create an instance on that alias type.

Comment: @Finkelson - X#Y means it's the Y of some X.  You still need the X there, even if you don't care which particular one it is.

Comment: @Finkelson There are many types for which you can't just create an instance: traits, abstract types, structural types, etc. Nothing special about projection types here.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Ok, and why do we need this feature then? What are the purposes of it?

Comment: 1. Your own example shows that we can have methods which take (or return) this type, call methods defined on it, etc. 2. To avoid path-dependent type `x.Y` which has its own issues. 3. For Java interoperation (it only has the equivalent of `X#Y`, not `x.Y`). Etc.